# Corona - Physics sliding on a surface (top down view)

Tags: coronasdk, physics

How do you simulate sliding, image a circle on screen and its sliding across the screen background. Or a puck sliding in an air hockey game.

This app shows exactly what I want if you care to see an example in action!

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/puck-puck/id463455207?mt=8

The app is free and put it there in case someone wanted to download it to exactly see what I was talking about. My current method is using physics.start() and setLinearVelocity(200, -300), then when the object is returning "falling" down screen i physics.pause() this gives appearance of fast - gradual stop. Wondering if another way so I could use friction to change things up.

Comment: Screenshots of the app are not informative. You want to simulate *friction?* When a sliding object gradually slows down and stops?

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of force and acceleration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sliding friction is a force with a constant magnitude and a direction opposite to the direction of motion.

The magnitude is a free variable you can adjust to get the motion you like. In real life it's proportional to the normal force (the force perpendicular to the surface, related to the weight) and a coefficient of kinetic friction (which is a measure of how "frictiony" the interface is -- ice or sandpaper).

Kinetic friction stops when the motion stops. Then *static* friction takes over, which is similir to kinetic but a little stronger, and applies as long as the object stands still. A common mistake is to botch this transition, so that the object winds up oscillating at low speed.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but unsure how to just a simple rect with physics, ie friction like ice, then have a circle slide on it. Only know how to have object interact with each other but not one on top of another. I dont think its possible....?

Comment: @user1173037: What do you want the rectangle to do? Move?

Comment: Rect will be like an air hockey table, a static body, which can have low or high friction. The circle will slide according to the friction of the table.

Comment: @user1173037: Does the table have different friction in different places?

Comment: no, just a table... think its more a 3D app the one i looked at cannot be done.

Comment: @user1173037: If it's just a circle moving in front of a background, then forget about interaction. Just get the motion of the circle right and you're done. *You don't need to think of the table as a body.*